# Removing values from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, drop

I am trying to remove these values from this column ProductType - type:int64 from a dataframe (df2):

```
df3 = df2.drop(df2.index[df2['ProductType'] == '100', '109', '110', '118', '123', '124', '143', '153', '163', 
                                        '173', '179', '190', '191', '196', '197', '200', '205', '206', 
                                        '208', '209', '211', '214', '215', '216', '219', '221', '222', 
                                        '223', '225', '226', '401', '999'], inplace = True)
```

AttributeError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

How can I fixed this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
removed_lst = ['100', '109', '110', '118', '123', '124', '143', '153', '163', 
               '173', '179', '190', '191', '196', '197', '200', '205', '206', 
               '208', '209', '211', '214', '215', '216', '219', '221', '222', 
               '223', '225', '226', '401', '999']

df3 = df2[~df2["ProductType"].isin(removed_lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

data = data.drop(columns="ProductType")

print(data)

Comment: I would like to select specific values under ProductType

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
df3 = df2.drop(df2[(df2['ProductType']== '100')|(df2['ProductType']== '109')|(df2['ProductType']== '110')].index)
```